# In EditText ,text should come after 1 space

Tags: android

In edittext the text is coming leftmost corner. but i want to display the text after one space . so it should be more readable.

Any one can help me in this problem.which tag in edit text i have to use.

Comment: Why not just set paddings for your text field of, say, 5dp?

Comment: use leftpadding in your editText view as android:paddingLeft="4dp".

Comment: yes , its working fine. but my problem was i have written the tag for background set as textfield. now i deleted that tag and by default it is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try providing margins around your EditText Background like this,

```
     <EditText android:id="@+id/tickets_value"
     android:layout_width="50dip"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:padding="5dip"
     />
```

Comment: The margin will just move the `EditText` away from the edge of its parent. The text inside the `EditText` will be as close of the edge of the `EditText` as before. OP needs to change the padding.

Comment: Sure. OP may want to only change the padding on one side, so as @Aleks G suggested, I would recommend `android:paddingLeft="5dp"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either the padding or the margin element of the view.

While margin offsets the entire view the padding offsets the content within the view.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html